# Nmap scanning in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: scanner, nmap

I have started to leran nmap in ubuntu.
I am ruuning the command  `$ nmap localhost` in ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
It is running perfectly and the output is

```
Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-08-22 16:27 IST
All 1000 scanned ports on localhost (127.0.0.1) are closed

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

But it is not showing which ports are open and which are closed as shown in the book **Nmap-Cookbook The fat free guide to network scanning**

[image: Screenshot from book]

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows ports that are open, not the closed ones.

In your command output, `nmap` tells `All 1000 scanned ports on localhost (127.0.0.1) are closed`, so there is no open ports to show, as in this example:

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-08-22 15:02 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000028s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
All 1000 scanned ports on localhost (127.0.0.1) are closed

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.02 seconds
```

As suggested by *sark*, you can check that `nmap` is working fine by opening a tcp port, for instance by using `nc -l 1234` in another console.
The expected result will be:

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-08-22 14:42 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000041s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
1234/tcp open  hotline

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Pim is on the money here - I'd like to write this as a comment to Pim's answer but I haven't got the rep yet! 
Why not start a service like SSH to open the port, run the scan again and you'll see port 22 open. The screen shot you provided shows the author has a few services running on their local machine.